# i18next + wordpress - custom path for the /locales folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, i18next

Is there any way i can pass a custom path for the `i18next` call? It searches for the `locales` folder in the site root. But if i'm using it in a WordPress plugin, i must pass a custom path with my plugin folder url, due wordpress structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way... but why would you want to? WordPress itself provides a way to localize JS through [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).